# cambiar dato null con isnull sql server

Tags: sql-server

necesito cambiar un valor null, he averiguado sobre la función "isnull()" pero la verdad en cuanto a sintaxis hay cosas que no me quedaron claras, he hecho un procedimiento almacenado de la sieguiente manera:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE añadir_fecha_clase 

@fecha_inicio datetime,
@fecha_fin datetime
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
if exists (select id from Clases)
begin 

update Clases set fecha_inic=@fecha_inicio,@fecha_fin=@fecha_fin
end
else
if(@fecha_fin is null and @fecha_fin='')  
begin
 --** ?? **--
end
END
GO
```

la idea es que si la fecha final es nula la pueda cambiar por medio de un dateadd que le sume dos horas a la fecha de inicio obteniendo como resultado la hora final si el valor queda nulo o de por sí vacio ('')

Comment: Entonces esto de debería ser AND, sino OR 
*if(@fecha_fin is null and @fecha_fin='')*

Comment: en verdad `@fecha_fin` es datetime, así que no puede ser `@fecha_fin = ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ISNULL` te debería servir perfecto para esto. Claro que tienes diferentes problemas en tu sintaxis, actualmente estás tratando de usar `UPDATE` sobre una variable en vez de sobre una columna...pero sin duda el problema más grande es que no estás recibiendo el id de la clase que quieres actualizar:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE añadir_fecha_clase 

@fecha_inicio datetime,
@fecha_fin datetime,
@id int --estoy asumiendo el tipo de datos
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
if exists (select id from Clases where id = @id)
begin 
    update dbo.Clases 
    set fecha_inic = @fecha_inicio,
        fecha_fin = ISNULL(@fecha_fin,DATEADD(HOUR,2,@fecha_inicio)
    where id = @id;
end

END
```

Comment: amigo te agradezco mucho por tu aporte pero tengo un pequeño problema:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: tuve que hacer otro script pero con más validaciones pero tu ejemplo me permitio desarrollarlo de  manera satisfactoria